# Magento Certification: Is it worth it?

Tags: certification

How many people on here are Magento certified?

What was your experience with the process? Since becoming certified, do you believe your certification has provided any benefits to your work or career?

Comment: Whilst a fair question. I'm not exactly sure that it is valid for the Q&A format of this website.

Comment: I agree with @sonassi, it's rather OT for this Q&A site. But I'll post a short answer here as a comment... Yes, it is well worth it. The certification is not just clout for a resumé and the company you work for. The experience of getting certified alone should be considered "worth it." You will learn things you didn't know of before, and highlight areas you may need to spend time digging into more. When all is said and done, you've learned a great deal *and* you then have the certification to show for it...which will help you get a job at a reputable agency should you desire one.

Answer (score 7):

I've done the certification some months ago and it was a benefit for me to learn things in Magento I never had any contact so far. Magento is a really big system and you can solve most problems in a dozen of different ways, this leads to usually stick in your comfort zone and use the same solution path again and again. By being forced learning new ways, during preparation for the certification, I've learned so much cool new things and there seem to be a lot of better ways to solve different things, than I would've done it before.

Answer (score 4):

Magento Certification when done will help in your resume plus your company in there marketing.

But if you study with a thought of grabbing the design patterns,understanding EAV, making out Magento architecture when looking at question and there answers then it will help you a long way.

If you just remember answers for the sake of exams you might pass but main benefits wouldn't be there.

In my case when I started studying for Magento and it helped Me have indepth understanding of  EAV, Events and Observers,Magento design patterns, its XML configuration system, override system etc.
Thus helping Me in My Magento skills.

Answer (score 4):

Certification is / certified developers are necessary for partners per their partner agreement. Beyond that, certification is going a decent bullet point on your résumé and will likely be a "positive" for prospective employers or clients.

Like so many other things in our knowledge-based industry, you get out of certification what you put into it. While developing and reviewing some of the test questions, I learned *a lot* of things I didn't know. While leading my coworkers through Vinai's study group kit I continued to learn things even after I had already passed the exam, and my coworkers learned a lot as well.

That said, given that the passing percentage is pretty low (too low, in my opinion), it is possible to "squeak by" and get relatively little out of it. It's also possible to pass with a tons of working experience but a dearth of architectural awareness; the latter being more valuable to me in my role as a part time recruiter.

Slight self-link, but [I've answered a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11994641/833795).

Comment: I need details about "Vinai's study group kit" and link of slight self-link

Answer (score 0):

Only for your resume and the company you work for that they can state that they have "certified" programmers..

for the rest... it's wasted time and effort.