# Developer Plus Certification

Tags: certification

I am planning to take the Certified Developer Plus exam. I have gone through the study guide, but have some questions that one of you might be able to shed some light on.

1. As stated on the Magento website, the exam is based on both CE and
   EE. My question is, for some sections where the EE and CE differ
   (like URL rewrites, Indexing) the study guide seems to imply that the
   answers will be based on the CE rather than the EE. Is this correct?
2. Related to question 1, would this mean that the only EE modules that
   I will be asked to answer questions on, are the ones specified in
   chapter 11 (Enterprise Edition)? In other words, are chapters 1-10
   based on CE and chapter 11 on EE?
3. Chapter 12 - Challenge questions. I have read in a thread that these
   must be answered correctly 100%, otherwise one cannot pass the
   test. Is this correct?  Do all challenge questions come for sections
   that are already covered in the Study Guide?

Answer (score 2):

1) Since EE is based off of CE, all of the questions are related to EE, and the plus portion of the exam is specific EE questions that CE doesn't include.

2) Yes, the main difference between EE and CE, code wise, is the additional EE modules that are a part of the CE code base.

3) I'm not 100% positive on the grading scale, but I believe the EE portion of the exam are a small number of questions, ~12 or so if I can remember correctly.  I took the test in 2012 so it may be a lot different now.  But I would assume to get Plus certified you would need to get at least 70% of those EE specific questions correct.

Also, keep in mind Magento 2 is slowly maturing and that the old certification will not port over to Magento 1 I believe.  While it still makes you marketable to those still running 1.0, but I would suspect over the next coming years Magento 2.0 will start to take over 1.0.

Good luck!

Resources to prepare for the exam:

- http://blog.belvg.com/category/magento-news/developer-certification
- [Magento Certification: Is it worth it?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/magento-certification-is-it-worth-it)
- [Studying to become a Magento Certified Developer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81/studying-to-become-a-magento-certified-developer)